# File naming conventions when sending file back and forth via email?

Tags: writing, email, collaboration

I often edit a manuscript draft with co-authors by sending drafts of a document back and forth via email. Depending on who I am working with, cloud-based solutions to working collaboratively are not always an option.

After some back and forth a lot of interim drafts begin floating around, so a lot of my co-authors either initial, date, or number a working document when we send it back and forth for edits. Some do none of this at all. I am wondering if there is a correct way to "name" a document when collaborating via email. Is there a consensus on best practices for file-naming conventions when collaboratively editing via email?

Comment: "correct" not sure, common sense yes - dates or version 1, version 2 or dates, times and initials are all common...

Comment: The key of good VCS such as git is to have a link to which the previous version is. So, ask them to mark their version with their new version number and name, at the least, but, ideally, add from which version they have constructed it (or multiple of these if this was a merge).

Comment: @CaptainEmacs No need to do such manual drudgery; that's what [`git format-patch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch) is for ;)

Comment: @Warbo If they can use git format-patch, they know how to use git. If they know how to use git, they will use LaTeX. If they use LaTeX, they are capable of using online repositories. If they are capable of using online repositories, they would use them for a joint document. If they would use them, the question would not have been asked. Hence, they must use either Google Docs or Word. Google docs does not have version problems. It follows that they use Word, email with incoherent threads, and inconsistent file naming for version control and they think "git format-patch" is a Romulan swearword.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs I have various collaborators that use Latex and still exchange files via e-mail. Git is more advanced tech than Latex.

Comment: Sadly, there is no strictly "correct" method of version control.

There should be, but how could that be implemented across different operating systems, software and Users?

Captain Emacs might be wholly right. Either way, you need to develop your own modus operandi which even if it doesn't go so far as to demand specific procedures, at least tells everyone involved that they must agree a procedure, and stick to it.

Different co-authors have different priorities and all need to understand that if they won't collaborate, they will be responsible for any and all problems arising.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Indeed. But my inference goes the other way round. Warbo suggested using git. :-)

Comment: @CaptainEmacs: The shaky step in your chain is “If they use LaTeX, they are capable of using online repositories. […] Hence, they must use either Google Docs or Word.”  Like @ Federico, I’ve known several collaborators who were very happy with LaTeX but didn’t like using online repositories, and whose preferred workflow absolutely fit what’s described here.  I’m sure they would have been *capable* of using online respositories, but they weren’t *willing* to.

Comment: @PLL "Capable" is the point. But you are of course right, strictly spoken. What still stands in my argument is that, being ready and able to use git, the rest pretty much follows downstream. I probably should have placed LaTeX second last, but I intended it to be more humorous than anything, plus keeping in mind that LaTeX is suitable for git merging and therefore LaTeX usage follows from git usage, rather than Word usage. I should have connected the logic chain of repositories to both LaTeX *and* git usage as parents. "> Congratulations! You have killed the joke. The joke is now dead." ;-)

Comment: From my experience, git is to C as SVN is to Python. For non-programmers, SVN is often _the right tool for the job_.

Comment: Surely there is a startup somewhere that wants to use *the blockchain* for revision control. :)

Comment: If you are using LaTeX, collaborative tools like www.overleaf.com are very useful and avoid the need to know a version control system. They also avoid filling up your inbox. Many institutions have site licenses to them, and if not there are free plans available.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs - "If they know how to use git, they will use LaTeX." is not true at all in my experience.  Ever programmer at my workplace uses git.  Only a few with experience in academia would use LaTeX, and even then it tends to be the older members of the team.  In practice no-one uses it, because documents are not shared exclusively with people who use LaTeX.

Comment: @GuyG I had hoped my comment would appear as tongue-in-cheek as I had it in mind, but obviously not.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs - Probably just not when I skim-read comments...

Comment: @Artelius SVN is a fair choice, but it requires a central server (AKA a "cloud"). Git doesn't.

Comment: Date the file like 11nov.17.23.This.File....

Comment: To get back to the real question...  one can note there are real situations when shared servers are a problem, most notably when some people are in a jurisdiction that limits internet access and some aren't.  Are there still workarounds then?  Yes.  Do they become really inconvenient and for some people a net waste of time?  Yes.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I come from a field where none of these answers are going to work. Remember, most scientists aren't computer scientists.  As a grad student, sending professors arcane rules for naming conventions would probably just be ignored. Everyone has their own usual pattern, and even if they wanted to be helpful, might just forget when it comes time to save. What irks me is people that put spaces in filenames.

As much as I plan to improve this process if I ever run my own lab, here's what you have to do:

**The first author** (or author leading the publication, or the corresponding author, or someone picked to facilitate) **runs the show.**

1. When you send out a draft, state a date for when you'd like to receive comments by (two weeks is a good rule-of-thumb). Don't make your own edits in the meantime if you can help it.
2. When you send out a draft, put a date on it. When people start sending you comments, sometimes people will be kind and edit one that someone has already edited. IME, that doesn't always happen.
3. At the end of the time period, or once you've received everyone's comments, use Word's [document merge tool](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/combine-document-revisions-f8f07f09-4461-4376-b041-89ad67412cfe).
4. Save with the new date, and start incorporating edits and responding to comments.
5. Rinse and repeat.

You will end up with a lot of files, with different dates. I keep the files from step #4 only, once you are confident in the merge. Frankly, space is cheap, and personally I find it easier to open `paper-200303.docx` to find an old comment than revision tools (for Word). When the paper is accepted, you can delete the old versions.

Answer (score 35):

**Not using version control is bad.**

> Depending on who I am working with, cloud-based[, version controlled] solutions to working collaboratively are not always an option.

**You can use cloud-based solutions even when some collaborators are against them.** All you need to do is: Download and email the cloud version to collaborators that refuse to use the cloud, and upload whatever they send back.

Comment: The OP knows that not using version control is bad. This does not answer their question.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper If an OP is following an ill-advised path, should we help them along (by answering their questions) or guide them onto a better path? I believe the latter is more useful and should be considered a valid answer, which is what I believe my answer does

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108066/discussion-on-answer-by-user2768-file-naming-conventions-when-sending-file-back). Leaving these two to summarize the discussion.

Comment: I feel this is misleading as VCS != cloud. If there are objections because the cloud is bad, e.g. because it is under foreign control and well cloudy (if it's there it's there and if it's gone it's gone...), you can suggest to setup a private VCS/git repo!

Comment: That sounds like a lot of work for the person co-ordinating the cloud repository! And remember, being "against" a cloud solution is not necessarily being obstructive for the sake of it -- sometimes there are good reasons (security of confidential data; collaborators at different institutions; compatibility issues of a specific cloud solution for those of us who do not have the latest, shiniest hardware and operating systems; ethical objections to giving custom to a provider that dodges taxes)

Answer (score 12):

The key to modern version control such as git is knowing the parent documents of a document. You thus need to be able to reconstruct which the immediately previous version is.

So, ask them to mark their version with their new version number and name, at the least, but, ideally, add from which version they have constructed it (or multiple of these if this was a merge)

Thus, at the very least, OP could use -.-.txt.

So you could deduce that that rollingstones-4.2-PK.txt has been derived by PK from (probably) 4.1. As well as rollingstones-4.2-IR.txt has also probably 4.1 as parent, but modified independently by somebody else. When you merge versions with the same number, you can omit the author and just give it the following number, e.g. if rolling stones-4.3.txt is a merge of the previous ones.

If you can afford to and people are disciplined, it would help to mark the immediate predecessor, though: rollingstones-4.4-UM-from-4.3-PK.txt. This is a bit clunky and a poor imitation of modern VCS such as git, but it allows you to deduce the parent(s) of the present version which is all you ultimately need.

To facilitate that, ask people, directly on downloading the latest version, to duplicate it and modify its name immediately to reflect the parenthood of the downloaded version.

Comment: This is a great suggestion, and it works well when it works. My only worry is what happens if some contributors fail to change the file name after the edit (e.g. because "oh, it's so minor, just a line here and there"). We still fall back to history of emails to recover the tree of edits. Filename conventions can be done wrong, but email client keeps order regardless. That's why I think emails should be the primary mechanism.

Comment: @DmitrySavostyanov Well, email is just a timeline. Basically it means, you have to dig out the possible dependencies anyway by hand. Essentially dynamic time warping, split according to authors, by hand. Yuck!

Comment: Well, email keeps a tree of replies, so if people download the file from an email, edit it and email by responding to the same email, we have the tree of edits, not "just the timeline".

Comment: @DmitrySavostyanov How do you merge? And what do you do if a new thread is opened? I am kind of beginning to get your point, but if you suggest email as VCS, perhaps you should edit your answer to explain the "algorithm" as to how to manage email as VCS. I am not fully able to understand how one would find the parents in your algorithm. I got that far to see that threads with individual correspondents would correspond to "branches".

Comment: Sorry, I thought it's pretty obvious, because emails are a tree and git is a tree, so it's really the same. Of course there is no automatic merge, which is a huge pain and the main reason to use git.

Comment: @DmitrySavostyanov In emails, there is not only no automatic merge, but no merge at all, which means, you may not know who the full sets of parents are - in emails you have usually only one parent, and sometimes even orphaned branches. That's why I do not think that emails are a good (ahem adequate) model and I suggested a more explicit approach. Of course, where the explicit approach breaks, you can then further enhance it by taking the clues from the email, but it's not something I'd like to do on a regular basis as a user. Anyway, thank you for clarifying.

Comment: If an collaborator sends you an email with a filename that doesn't correspond to your system then rename it so that it does. If collaborators are using word (mostly likely) then word includes a merge feature that works pretty well.

Comment: This answer relies too much on people following directions.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist OP asked for naming conventions. If you want to avoid people have to "follow directions", you need a tool that funnels activity in a particular way, such as Overleaf or Google docs, but this was not listed by OP as option.

Answer (score 12):

I'm surprised nobody has mentioned the classical "token"/"cookie" system.

The way I used to write papers with coauthors 20 years ago was using an informal token system.  If I wanted to edit Section 1 of the paper, even just to fix a single typo, I had to follow these steps:

- Email all coauthors with the text *"I am claiming the token for section 1."*
- Edit section 1
- Email all coauthors with their edited version of Section 1 and the text *"I am releasing the token for Section 1."*

Nobody was allowed to keep the token for any section more than some agreed limit. typically 24 hours, but that often shrank to 2 hours or even 15 minutes as deadlines got closer.  In principle, everyone could keep their own local copy of the paper up to date, but in practice, it was helpful for one co-author to periodically recalibrate by claiming the token for *the entire paper*.

As long as everyone followed token discipline, there was no need to worry about file names.  There were no version disputes, because the most recent version of Section 5.4 was always **by definition** in the most recent email releasing the token for Section 5.4.  In particular, if you branched, it was *your* responsibility to merge correctly, not your coauthors'.

On the other hand, co-authors (including both PhD students and tenured Luddites) who *didn't* follow token discipline found themselves involved in fewer papers afterward.

While my paper collaboration has mostly moved to Overleaf+git, I do actually still use this system on the unavoidable but thankfully increasingly rare occasions that I need to collaborate on a Word document with someone who doesn't have access to Word Online or Google Docs.

**tl;dr: Don't do this unless you have to.**

Comment: Sounds like working with a broken version of CVS. :-S

Comment: It sounds messy from the outside, but I can see how this can work well. Though what happens if you work on Section 2 and another co-author starts working on Section 3 on parallel. Who merges the two sections at the end?

Comment: I believe it was answered - if you want, you can update your local document but usually someone says "I claim token for the paper" and updates it for everyone.
I also believe that sections might often be on separate .tex files that are all included in the main file, so no merging is actually required.

Comment: If someone emailed me "I'm claiming the token for section 1," I would have no idea what they meant (except for after reading your answer).

Comment: @AzorAhai It doesn't matter what system you use, unless you tell the people which one you are using it won't work. Same here. It's clunky, but it has the great advantage that it does not rely on a specific technology.

Comment: @Džuris I only ever did this with one-tex-file papers.  Maintaining multiple files for anything shorter than a book makes things much messier, in my experience.

Comment: @JeffE I feel exactly the opposite :D Navigating file longer than a screen and a half is terrible, I do file per section all the time.

Comment: We even used this when using git/svn just to avoid merge conflicts or wasted time when two people fix the same spelling error.

Comment: 24 hours sounds harsh. Can we not at least pretend to respect other people's weekends? (yes, I know none of us works just Monday–Friday 09:00–17:00, but that does not mean we should allow ourselves to be under constant pressure to turn-around things that quickly all the time)

Comment: @anon If you're not going to work over the weekend, release your tokens on Friday afternoon.  (Better to release the token before you're completely finished with your changes than to make other people wait for you.)  Said differently: If you have a token, you are by definition working, even if it's a weekend.

Comment: @JeffE Ah, so you can release a token early. A good idea, provided other co-authors do not mind comments such as:"There is a great cross-reference I have in mind to develop the point in paragraph 4, but I cannot remember the details -- I will do some reading over the weekend to see if I can find it again."

Answer (score 4):

If you want to avoid cloud solutions and use email, maybe choose a VCS which works offline (i.e. is distributed, like git) and has support for email (preferably built-in, like git).

There are many ways to set up such a workflow, [here's an example for git](https://drewdevault.com/2018/07/02/Email-driven-git.html). Essentially: you work in git like normal, and when you want to send someone your changes you can use `git send-email`; after receiving an email containing changes you would like to apply (e.g. maybe after some back-and-forth discussion in reply to a `git send-email` message) you can pipe that email into a command like `git am` to incorporate the changes.

git is well-suited to use over email, since this was its original use-case and is hence the preferred and best-supported way to use it.

Comment: you are assuming they will send you a git formatted email

Comment: Most likely, they use Word. See my comment above :-)

Comment: Implicitly, the question implies the use of some binary file such as Word as pointed out by others. Version control can be used with binary files, but is typically not that useful. If they use Word, I guess one could extract the xml but lets not go down that avenue...

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't strictly answer the question, because it is about adopting **no convention at all.** As others have said, it is usually difficult to get authors to stick to the same system.

Assuming you use a format (e.g. MS Word) which has some sort of "track changes" feature, or a text format (e.g. LaTeX) which you can `diff`:

- Let authors rename files in any way they please
- One person (perhaps unofficially) takes responsibility for maintaining some sort of continuity of the document (i.e. keeping the structure and flow OK)
- If the document versions diverge, this person uses the "track changes" feature to pull them back together
- And then emails the result to everyone saying "I've incorporated everyone's changes"
- Some authors won't work off this version straight away, especially if they were in the middle of writing something or working closely with someone else

  - But eventually they will because they don't want to be left out of the loop
  - In the meantime the "maintainer" just keeps adding their new changes to their "master" document
  - *The key is that **they don't need to do any work** to switch to the master version.*

Authors that aren't off doing their own thing will know which version to choose (the one that says "everyone's changes are in here!")

This has many other benefits like saving most authors time and hunting through emails, removing the danger of changes being lost, stressing authors about continuity problems, and having someone who is looking at the big picture of the document and can discuss that with other authors.

Answer (score 2):

A "modified date plus initials" combo might help, perhaps combined by a journal abbreviation if a template is followed, e.g. "Nature 12-12 BH". Personally, I find dates easier to track than version numbers. In any case, forking the versions must be avoided at all costs.

If Github/ Dropbox/ OneDrive etc are not an option, an online LaTex editor such as Overleaf might be, where each collaborator can work on one single version of the paper. Another solution is e-mailed download links, since one does not need to have an account to access a file (this has the advantage of process ownership and monitoring but includes more hassle). If lack of internet is a problem, I cannot think of something.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: In my personal opinion, the best option is to **keep the filename** at all times.

Here's my reasoning. The filename tells us what purpose the document serves, which information it contains. The meta information (who is the author, when the last edit was made) is saved in file properties or in special fields within the file itself. The history of edits is traditionally maintained using some version control system (VCS).

In your case, you use email as your VCS. The emails are timestamped and your email client allows you to sort emails according to this date. Emails also give you information about the last author. If people send their edits by responding to the email with the version from which the edit was made, the email client keeps the whole tree of edits, just like git, allowing you to find a parent for every version. A tree of emails is a direct equivalent of a git tree. You may want to create a filter to put all emails with this file attached in a special folder to separate them from the rest of your communications. Other than that, email is already a minimalist and incomplete (no automatic merge for example), but working VCS.

Since you already have a VCS, modifying filenames to code the same information is unnecessary and inconvenient, and should be avoided.

PS: And it goes without saying, email is a much poorer VCS compared to e.g. git, so you should at least offer your collaborators to try using a better system for collaboration.

Comment: Email is a horrible VSC, emphatically not recommended. At the very least, OP could use <original filename>-<version number>.<version-subnumber>-<last change author>.txt. This is a poor imitation of modern VCS such as git, in terms of allowing one to deduce the parent(s) of the present version (which is the key here, especially with multiple authors). All said, not using a proper VCS is definitely a pain.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs Perhaps, you would like to post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you must share files in such a way (and often you just have to, despite the many wonderful version control, cloud file-sharing and collaborative editing tools out there), I suggest a format such as 
mainfilename-timestamp-initials.

E.g., `cure_for_cancer-202005011030-jb.tex`, where the timestamp is for 10.30am on May 1, 2020.
That makes it easy to sort multiple versions of the same file lexicographically (i.e., by file name). But of course, you've then got the challenge of getting collaborators to follow the same convention.

Comment: It's not human readable or writable.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Meh. I'm a human, and I read those things all the time. YMMV. Choose a timestamp format you prefer, but that particular order at least sorts well.

Comment: The ISO date/time format is basically that one, and it includes some better defaults for separators.

Comment: minute time stamps are probably a little fine-grained, days work just fine (especially if there are initials too)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the single biggest problem is that the file's "last modified" metadatum often ends up reflecting the time it was "last saved/downloaded". That means that establishing where it fits into a workflow can be a nightmare.

My solutions, which do not require computing expertise (I work in a humanities discipline, so one cannot assume everyone is comfortable using the suggestions in other answers), are as follows:

- **enter dates of recent revisions and associated author monograms in the page header manually** (e.g.: "JB 31/04/2019; revised JRW 02/05/2019; JB comments 03/05/2019") -- this makes the information easy to find and ensures it is included on every page of a printout (yes, I like to comment on versions by annotating a printout by hand!); and
- **all file names commence with the date of the version in** *yyyymmdd* **format** (e.g.: "20190503_JB_comments_re_20190502_JRW_Methodology"), in order to facilitate quick sorting and unambiguous identification of recent versions on computer filesystems.

Answer (score -1):

I would take a stab at [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/), as suggested by the people who run Github.

In short: append a series of three digits to the end of the filename. For example: myfile-1.0.0.txt. When someone sends it back to you, whatever they respond with, you can tick up your next version to some identifier in that format which clearly counts as numerically greater.

Comment: This doesn't work if two people edit 1.0.0 independently.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist: So the primary author/OP takes it and bumps it up by one. If the co-authors refuse to help at all, then it's the OP's responsibility to correct.